# How to get amount of energy from extension structure?

Tags: javascript, screeps

In game each structures have property `structureType` that may be one of the following: `spawn`, `extension`, `road`, `constructedWall`, `rampart`. http://www.screeps.com/docs/Structure.php#structureType

So in the simulation we can see that the extension structure may contain some amount of energy.
But API Docs the structures don't have `energy` property.

Comment: you need to add more information about your problem. work on your code formatting (i can't edit it for you, cause i have no idea how `screeps` works) and maybe provide more code.

Comment: edit your question to put the information in there. comments are not the right place for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was missing in the API. We've just added it, should be working now.

Comment: It would be great if extensions have another use, like temporary storage.

Answer (score 0):

Nice, but how we can use energy stored in an extension? It seems it has not method transferEnergy unlike   a spawn.

Indeed extension is not a storage but something like amplifier of spawn.

http://screeps.com/docs/Spawn.php:

> Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_EXTENSIONS -13 There is not enough loaded spawn extensions in the room to create a creep with the given body.

Comment: For now, energy in extension is used for create creeps with 6+ mods.